# Entity Framework -> Get records from DB one by one or get them at once. Which is faster?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have collection of Id`s which are from two tables in the DB. Both objects have one common property which i need. I will select only this property always, but my question is:

Is it better to split Id's collection into two and make two queries from DB or use loop and take every single object, one by one, from the Database?

1st approach

```
List<byte[]> binariesToAttach = new List<byte[]>();

IEnumerable<someObj> Type1objects = toAppend.Where(a => a.Type == FileType.Type1Obj).Select(f => f.Id);
IEnumerable<someObj> Type2objects = toAppend.Where(a => a.Type == FileType.Type2Obj).Select(f => f.Id);

binariesToAttach.AddRange(this.UnitOfWork.Example1Repository.Get(s => Type1objects.Any(a => s.Id == a)).Select(f => f.Content));
binariesToAttach.AddRange(this.UnitOfWork.Example2Repository.Get(s => Type2objects.Any(a => s.Id == a)).Select(f => f.Content));

foreach (var item in binariesToAttach)
{
    // TODO something
}
```

or 2nd approach:

```
foreach (var item in toAppend)
{
    if (item.Type == FileType.Type1Obj)
    {
        byte[] data = this.UnitOfWork.Example1Repository.Get(a => a.Id == item.Id).Select(a => a.Content).FirstOrDefault();

        // TODO something
    }
    else
    {
        byte[] data = this.UnitOfWork.Example2Repository.Get(a => a.Id == item.Id).Select(a => a.Content).FirstOrDefault();

        // TODO something
    }
}
```

Personaly i think 2nd approach is more understandable and that`s why I prefer him. But if 1st is more optimized..

Comment: On the second approach, you fetch the data from DB for every toAppend item.There can be many DB hits in this approach. First one is better

Comment: @Curious: That's an answer, not a comment. Comments are intended to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short and simple answer is that for every call to the database, several actions need to be taken, such as opening the connection, authentication, authorization, closing the connection (probably more I'm forgetting but I'm no DBA so I'm a bit fuzzy on the specific actions taken).

These actions are taken for every request. The more requests you fire, the more work needs to be done. **With a sufficiently large volume of requests, this time/effort becomes a significant drain on performance**.

It is therefore generally better to fetch data all at once. There are situationcal exceptions possible here but you should err on the side of loading as much as you can in as few requests as possible.

---

*As a general future tip: you could have easily benchmarked this yourself by writing a small console application that either fetches 1000 rows of data at once or one by one, and compared the time needed to complete either task.*

---

As an aside, there are issues in your first approach. `Any(a => a.Id == a.Id)` is always `true` since a value always equals itself. I assume the code you added isn't used in practice and was used more for demonstrating intent in this question.

Comment: About the ``` Any(a => a.Id == a.Id) ``` -> yes it was type error :) I`ve already made some tests. 1st aproach looks better when records count increases